# Hibernate OneToMany OrderBy messes up main query

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-annotations, hibernate-onetomany

I have a class Video that I'm querying for in my Hibernate and I am ordering the results by `Order.desc("id")`.
The query works as expected. However, if I add a `@OneToMany` annotation in Video to include the comments, I also add an `@OrderBy` to that same annotation (I need to the comments to be `ordered by "createdTime"`).

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "videoId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@OrderBy("commentTime")
public List<Comment> getComments()
```

This breaks the main query - the return of videos is now wrong: it orders SQL to return videos with no comments first, followed by 1 comment, etc:

```
order by comments6_.commentTime asc, this_.videoId desc
```

I need to only sort videos by their ids.

Comment: Perhaps it might be worth using Hibernate's `@Sort` instead which performs the ordering in-memory after it's retrieved the data? You will need to provide a `Comparator` for this though. At least this way you know it won't affect your SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `@Sort` instead:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "videoId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@Sort(type = SortType.COMPARATOR, comparator = CommentTimeComparator.class)
public List<Comment> getComments()
```

This way you know it won't affect your SQL. It may also offer a performance improvement by taking pressure off your database - for example, if you have a number of `@OneToMany` associations on the same entity that you want sorting.

Comment: Sort is deprecated and should use SortComparator